# matplotlib only plot one figure at a time

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have 2 figures to plot in a python program. I run the code by:

```
python myprog.py
```

The two figures are shown one at a time: the second figure does not show until the first figure is closed. Is there a way to plot all the figures at once? An example code is shown as below.

```
import pylab as plt

x  = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
y1 = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
y2 = [3.0,2.0,1.0]

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y1,'b')
plt.show()

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x,y2,'r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just remove your first `plt.show()`.

Comment: I believe the comment by @CTZhu above actually answers this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official documentaion](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot):

> matplotlib.pyplot.plot(*args, **kwargs)
>
> Plot lines and/or markers to the Axes. args is a variable length
>   argument, **allowing for multiple x, y pairs with an optional format
>   string**

So you can just do this:

```
import pylab as plt

x  = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
y1 = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
y2 = [3.0,2.0,1.0]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y1,'b', x,y2,'r')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

To plot multiple subplots to show multiple graphs, which is what I believe the question was asking rather than plot multiple lines using a single plot command, use subplots as follows:

```
import pylab as plt

x  = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
y1 = [1.0,2.0,3.0]
y2 = [3.0,2.0,1.0]

fig = plt.figure()
axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
axes.plot(x,y1,'b')

axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
axes.plot(x,y2,'r')
plt.show()
```

Although plotting multiple instances works for the example, for more complicated graphs, having subplots is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use subplots to show both graphs on the same graph.